# Javascript gallery below menu popup

Tags: javascript, horizontal-scrolling, popupmenu

Im creating a mobile version for my website, and I'm currently busy with a 'image scroll' by swiping. I found a code on the internet I'm using, but it doesn't work with the menu i've created.
The menu that pops up, stays below the image scroller..
How do I get it to get below the opened menu?

Thanks for the help!

Regarding this page: http://m.tf2-29.com/TF_Members.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `z-index` of popmenu

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

```
.bbstable
{
   BACKGROUND: #1e201c;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   z-index: 2; /* set z-index higher than image scroller */
}
```

or remove `z-index: 1` in `.swiper-container`